# How to updatde current URL while uploading document in SharePoint 2013 using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to change URL while uploading document to SharePoint document library using CSOM.

Description:
We have 'XYZ' document library with following folder structure:

1. Folder 1

   - SubFolder 1

     ```
          - All Documents
     ```

Now I am trying to upload document at Folder 1. and after Drag and Drop document is getting uploaded to Folder 1. What I want to do here is, Whenever user try to upload document in Folder 1, it should get uploaded to SubFolder 1 . Is there any way to change URL of document in CSOM while its getting uploaded. So that it will get uploaded to 'SubFolder 1' even though user is doing DRagDrop  to 'Folder 1'.

I am getting current folder URL in state.Status= Uploading event. I want to update this URL by adding 'Subfolder 1' to currentURL , so that it will upload this document direct to updated URL.
Note: If you have any other way to do it please let me know. also Cant go for Server side code. need CSOM. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar requirements before and would recommend using a workflow for this. I have left out the step for getting the FormDigestValue by making a call to /_api/web/contextinfo, but that is needed in the request header.

The following URL format is used to call the API to move the document. [Here is some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileMoveTo) on the API.

/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Folder1/file.pdf')/moveto(newurl='/Folder1/SubFolder1/file.pdf',flags=1)

[image: Check if in Folder1]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @horinedev. However I cant go for Workflow. Whereas I have found SPDragUploadInfo has RootFolder parameter. and it gets loaded when page is loaded. I want to add CurrentYear in rootFolder, so that uploaded document will go to CurrentYear Folder in that document library. WPQRegisterDragUpload method present init.debug.js is used for defining value for this RootFolder. Please let me know If you know how to Override this method with custom code.